# Why UIScrollView delegate can not connect to itself?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I `Storyboard` I have a scrollview, and want to notify itself because itself is the delegate handler as well, about content offset changes. But I can not connect in `Storyboard`, why?

Delegate is defined in class:

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed cannot connect `UIScrollView` delegate to itself in Storyboard, seems like a bug or an oversight.

You can do a workaround - connect the delegate in your `CustomScrollView` initializer instead of a Storyboard. When view is loaded from storyboard, `init?(coder:)` is called.

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        delegate = self
    }
}
```